# make:entity fails for some existing entites

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I like to use `make:entity MyEntity` to ammend entities (add fields, getters, setters). Normally it gives the output:

```
$ sym make:entity MyEntity
Your entity already exists! So let's add some new fields!
```

However, for some entities this will result in

```
$ sym make:entity SomeOtherEntity
[ERROR] The file "src/Repository/SomeOtherEntity.php" can't be generated because it already exists.
```

The difference between the entities is their location:

`MyEntity` is in src/Entity

`SomeOtherEntity` is in src/Domain/Model

However, the entities are all included in the config, as I added

```
Model:
    is_bundle: false
    type: annotation
    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Domain/Model'
    prefix: 'App\Domain\Model'
    alias: Model
App:
    is_bundle: false
    type: annotation
    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
    prefix: 'App\Entity'
    alias: App
```

E.g. migrations work fine with this. It is just that `make:entity` fails. 
The question is, can I use `make:entity` for entities that are not loacated in the default locatio?

Any hint would be apppreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

In order to create brand new entity in different namespace with command `make:entity`, you can use command:

`php bin/console make:entity \\App\\Domain\\Model\\SomeOtherEntity`

If you use make:entity for existing entities, you should add flag `--regenerate` to the command.

So the command for regenerating getters and setters for existing entity will look a bit differently:

`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\\Domain\\Model\\SomeOtherEntity`

Comment: Thank you! Where is that default location (src/Entity) hardcoded? We can not change that? Because soon I will move all my entities to src/Domain/Model

Comment: For me it was single backslash! Please try it out and edit your answer if necessary. With double slash it was throwing an error`is not valid as a PHP class name (it must start with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores)`